# php Integrate with differnet SMS API

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I working on php system , and client must insert his sms api information to let system send sms automatically , so as you want SMS API's parameters are different , for example clickatell api need APIKEY , Message,Phone parameters, to insert it into url like this

```
http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&message=hello &phone=2331212312
```

but other's SMS API send sms using xml code or jsondata with different parameters like this

```
<Information>
   <UserNAme>xxxxx</UserNAme>
   <Password>xxxxx</Password>
  <Subject>Hello</Subject> 
</Information>
<Process>
 <Send>
   <Message>TEST Message</Message>
    <NO>5394153105</NO>
</Send>

</Process>';
```

as you see the first API using http request to send sms and the another one using json data to send sms , so how can I let user to set his SMS Api's information and let him to send SMS automatically .

Comment: Your question is unclear. `as you see the first API using http request to send sms and the another one using json data to send sms ` - You can pick different api's from clickatell's interface.  `so how can I let user to set his SMS Api's information and let him to send SMS automatically` - why user must set his api?

Comment: that because some users has account in clickatell api and another has account with the others api so user must insert his api's information to the system to allow it send sms automatically

Comment: `some users has account in clickatell api` - ok, `another has account with the others api` - ok, some other user has other api, please add more details, examples in Your question.

Comment: if you have account in one SMS API you will have information to send sms using that API for example some API required APIKEY number,MESSAGE , phone number to send sms message  , another  API KEY asking you to insert your's Username,Password, Message, Phone number to send sms so the buyer of my system must tell the system about his api information to let it send sms , I  hope I explained my problem clearly

Comment: So, different services require that you handle them differently … that still doesn’t explain what your actual _question_ is now. You will have to implement different methods then, based on which service your user is a customer of.

Comment: but there are many and many SMS API Provider so must I implement all that's api

Comment: @muhammadahmed of course You've to implement separately. You cannot tell to sms api providers: "guys let's use my common sms api".  btw most SMS providers have common protocol: `SMPP` but I don't think You can work with it :D

Answer (score 0):

You should get user data coming from your `<form>` and then send a HTTP request to the API.

```
// $_GET as example, you can use $_POST
$myUserApiKey = $_GET['userInputapiKey'];
$myUserMessage = $_GET['userInputMessage'];
$myUserPhone = $_GET['userInputPhone'];
$serverResponse = http_get("http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg", array("apiKey"=>$myUserApiKey, "message"=>$myUserMessage, "phone"=>$myUserPhone ));

switch ($serverResponse) {
// Handle API response here
}
```

In the case you need to handle multiple API's with parameters that are named differently, you have the choice to :

- Call the same script in which we will add a variable to find the API we will use
- Make multiple PHP scripts for each API you need to handle

In the case you want to choose the first solution, it should looks like :

```
// $_GET as example, you can use $_POST
$apiToUse = $_GET['userApiChoice']; // Can be a HTML <input type="radio"> with a value
$myUserApiKey = $_GET['userInputapiKey'];
$myUserMessage = $_GET['userInputMessage'];
$myUserPhone = $_GET['userInputPhone'];

if ($apiToUse == 1) { // We use the first API
  $serverResponse = http_get("http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg", array("apiKey"=>$myUserApiKey, "message"=>$myUserMessage, "phone"=>$myUserPhone ));

  switch ($serverResponse) {
  // Handle API response here
  }

} else if ($apiToUse == 2) {
// Implement Other API Here
} else {
// Here's an unknown API.. Handle that error here
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , but does your code working when the API using XML or json data?

Comment: If you mean "Does it works when parameters are named differently ?", then you will need to adjust parameters name. You have the choice of creating multiple PHP scripts for each API, or calling the same script by adding a GET or POST variable like "apiType". Adding a "if" to adjust the request. I'm editing my answer.